# Load geoJson in MapBox for editing with Leaflet.Draw

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I try to load **geoJson** data in **Mapbox** and edit it with the plugin [Leaflet.Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw)

Here is an example : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manusvs650/jfuLB/1/)

```
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

var geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [ ...........  ]
}


L.geoJson(geojson).addTo(featureGroup);
```

When i click to the edit button, i have an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined

Object seems to be **editable** but i can't modify it.

What is the correct way to add geojson object in mapbox **draw** layer ?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the solution :

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

Comment: I actually have the same issue. I'm using Mapbox though. I've tried adding this to my code, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. [Here's my post about it.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153097/using-mapbox-leafletjs-how-do-i-edit-imported-shapes-from-geojson) If you could take a look at it, I'd greatly appreciate it. It seems to be adding my GeoJSON to layers, but I'm still getting the same error that you got.

Comment: Actually, that seemed to do the trick aside from the fact that my circles aren't showing up as circles. That will certainly help me move forward though! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example using CoffeeScript:

```
drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup()
map.addLayer drawnItems

layers = L.geoJson geojson
layers.eachLayer (layer) => drawnItems.addLayer layer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to get mine to work (in addition to the above answers):

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (layer.getLayers) {
      layer.getLayers().forEach(function (l) {
        featureGroup.addLayer(l);
      })
    } else {
      featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
    }
  }
});
```

This was for a geojson that was a "Feature" type.